# Compute: $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x}^{1} e^{x/y}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Compute: $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x}^{1} e^{x/y}$

I just don't know how to compute this integral. I tried u = x/y, but that didn't really lead me anywhere. It was suggested by fellows on a IRC that I graph this, but I didn't really understand. Could anyone expand on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: By changing the order of integration:

$$\int_0^1 \int_x^1 e^{x/y} dy dx = \int_0^1 \int_0^y e^{x/y} dx dy$$

Now the inside integral can be evaluated by

$$\int_0^y e^{x/y} dx = y e^{x/y} |_0^y = y e^1 - y e^0$$

Comment: I just learned how to compute Double integrals today, sorry, but how/why are you able to switch the order of integration?

Comment: @Ozera Draw a picture of the region that you're integrating over, and check that both integrals describe the same region. Then we can reverse the order using Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: I drew the graph, but why is the bounds not: $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{y}^{0}$ ? Is it because since $x=1$ is the farthest line out, to find the difference we would subtract it by $x=y$ ? I'm not sure if that same argument works for when choosing bounds in a dy case though...

Comment: @Ozera Did you draw the region **and** shade in the interval that you're integrating over?

Comment: @Ataraxia Sorry, I drew but did not shade and consequently misunderstood my graph. I understand why the bounds are the way they are now. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_x^1e^{x/y}\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1\int_x^1e^t\frac{x}{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}x&&y=\frac xt\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^te^t\frac{x}{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}t&&\text{swap order}\\
&=\int_0^1e^t\frac{\frac12t^2}{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t&&\text{inner integral}\\[4pt]
&=\frac12(e-1)&&\text{outer integral}
\end{align}
$$